# touchesBegan EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line "[subview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];". When I remove that line, everything works out. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", subview);
        NSLog(@"%@", touches);
        NSLog(@"%@", event);
        [subview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Comment: *touchesBegan:withEvent:* is designed to be an event handler, why do you call it recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a backtrace, hard to say.

However, `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is not a method you should ever have to call from your code.  It should only be called by the system.

More likely than not, you are calling that method on a subview that can't handle it, so it calls it passes it along to its `superview`.... then, infinite-loop-boom.

Comment: The infinite loop was the issue I had. How would you pass a touch event to another view if you can't use touchesBegan:withEvent:?

Comment: @user1802143 You don't pass events to views, rather you override *NSResponder* methods to do that.

Answer (score -2):

You can not call the "touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event" directly, it's a delegate method in iOS which call by system. If you want to send the touch event to subview, why dont you define a method like "touchesBegan:",do you want to do in touchesBegan, and call it in like this:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", subview);
        NSLog(@"%@", touches);
        NSLog(@"%@", event);
        [subview touchesBegan];
    }
}`

Comment: My subviews are views from a third party framework and they already have built in recognizers for all the touch events. Is there a way to simply forward the touch events to all the subviews?

I have two subviews on a UIView and any action that occurs in one subview, I want it to occur in the other.

Comment: Note that said methods are not "delegate methods" at all;  they are a part of the event handling system.   Your suggested change effectively bypasses the system's design pattern.